# Datastore & Memcache consistency - Google App Engine & Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify, consistency

I'm having a pretty tough problem ensuring consistency in the datastore.
We're trying to do a sync job to BigQuery every 1 minute (cron) and are relying on the Datastore to store a timestamp for when the previous sync was completed.

We are still seeing eventual consistency when the object is loaded and I'm getting to hair-tearing time..

Both the Settings & ParentClass classes are stored in the Datastore as singletons, I.e. only one exists.

```
@Entity
public class Settings {

    @Parent
    private Key<ParentClass> parent = ParentClass.getKey();

    @Id
    private Long id = 123L;

    ...

    public Settings save(){
        ofy().cache(false).consistency(ReadPolicy.Consistency.STRONG).save().entity(this).now();
        return this;
    }

    public static Settings get(){
        Settings settings = ofy().cache(false).consistency(ReadPolicy.Consistency.STRONG).load().key(Key.create(ParentClass.getKey(), Settings.class, 123L)).now();
        if (settings == null) settings = create();
        return settings;
    }

    private static Settings create(){
        return new Settings().save();
    }

}
```

Does anyone know what's causing this being eventually consistent?

Edit: web.xml extract:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>asyncCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>asyncCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I saw that post there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269411/inconsistency-issue-with-objectify-query-result-and-datastore-viewer-result  Could you be having similar issues?  Mind posting your web.xml?

Comment: Since the `get()` method is doing a fetch-by-key, it _should_ always have strong consistency.

Comment: @Patrice,  I saw that post too, but alas.. Added the objectify filters to the post..

Comment: @tx802 - I agree, which is why I'm completely puzzled by this problem.. I have even renamed the Settings class to Setting after optimising as much as possible, but the problem still persists, sometimes even getting hour old objects which just does not make sense..

Comment: Also worth noting that this persists through flushing the memcache..

Comment: I usually use python for the datastore so I'm not that familiar with Objectify. Could it be a cache at THAT level that you're hitting? Or is Objectify hitting memcache? I'm wondering if the cache (false) skips memcache but not Objectify's cache? (Srsly.... your problem seems to be so weird i'm reduced to weird theories)

Comment: I've considered the possibility myself, but I'm sure it would have been rooted out if it was anything like that due to the popularity of the library.. It's either a very obvious mistake by one of us or (my favourite theory) a problem in the 1.9.18 as it started appearing after it was released..

Comment: If you have the `ObjectifyFilter`, you don't need the `AsyncCacheFilter`. `ObjectifyFilter extends AsyncCacheFilter`.

Comment: @stickfigure - Am I missing something or is that a new change in an upcoming release? 5.1.5: ObjectifyFilter extends AbstractFilter, not AsyncCacheFilter?

Comment: The `ObjectifyFilter` includes the behavior of the `AsyncCacheFilter` so you do not need both. In older versions this was implemented with inheritance, in recent versions it is via a different mechanism. Sorry about the misleading comment!

Comment: No worries, appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the internal session cache of Objectify.

Initially resolved by manually clearing the cache using ofy().clear() prior to the first load() and then improved further by upgrading to Objectify 5.1.5.

Comment: The session cache behavior is pretty thoroughly documented here: https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Caching. It's also mentioned in a FAQ: https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

Comment: I think the important point in the documentation is: `A get-by-key operation (single or batch) for a cached entity will return the entity instance without a call to the datastore or even to the memcache.`. Probably, the entity you are loading is already in the session cache, so objectify is making a local, simple hashmap lookup instead of memcache call.